# General Purpose Decision Tree Algorithm Code Implementations

Tags: java, objective-c, algorithm, tree, decision-tree

Are there any well-designed, general purpose decision tree implementations for iPhone or Java? I know with LINQ it would be quite trivial, but with Objective C and Java, it would be much more complex.

Basically, I want to drill down a set of objects based off any number of qualifications or attributes in my apps.

Answer (score 2):

You could try [Weka](http://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/~ml/weka/).  The API is somewhat obtuse and makes simple things complicated, but it's a very good machine learning library and it even comes with a GUI front end if you want to play around with the classes interactively before writing code that uses them programmatically.

Comment: While You are at Weka take a look at J48 classifier, which is a decision tree classifier.

Comment: I was hoping for a more code based answer. I am not trying to deal with datasets, just a finite set of objects.